# How to extend a TFieldDef in easy and safe way?

Tags: delphi, collections, delphi-2007

I need an advice in problem with TFieldDef. I need to add one additional string property to the TFieldDef called Description. I want to see that property when I iterate over TFieldDefs collection. How to do this in Delphi 2007?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mostly, you can't. But you can re-purpose another property such as `DisplayName` or `Tag`. You could also write a [class helper](http://blogs.embarcadero.com/abauer/2007/02/24/32322), but you'd have to store the data elsewhere.

Comment: DisplayName: not possible, it is not implemented in TFieldDef
Tag: I want String not an Integer
Class Helper: storing data elsewhere is not very convenient, not to mention I would have then free it explicitly? Thanks anyway Craig.

Comment: You can use strings with `Tag` if you reference a pointer or string list index. But you're going to have to come to grips with the fact that what you're asking is essentially unsupported. *Any* "solution" is going to be a bit hacky. And, yes, memory management is on you; there is no GC here.

Comment: I've realized that after my comment. +1 Craig for made me to think ;-)